# how to extract last digits of a class in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want use classes as variables.

like... if you give some element the class `fontColor_` and then write some color in hex, it is gonna turn the color that I put after `_`. and so on.

example:
    `<div class='fontColor_11d63b'>the color of this text is now blue</div>`

how is that possible?
is there any function that deletes the first N letters in a word, adds `#` in front and then assigns the resulting property to a certain element?

Comment: This seems a very odd approach:you seem to be re-inventing the `style` attribute. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: im just curious. im sorry if it's a silly question

Comment: `$("*[class*='fontColor_']").each(function () { // your code here });` for just start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just curious how to write such a function, here's a pure JavaScript way:

```js
document
.querySelectorAll("[class^=fontColor]")
.forEach(x => {
  x.style.color = "#"+x.classList[0].replace(/^fontColor_/,"")
})
```

```html
<div class='fontColor_FF0000'>the color of this text is now red</div>
<div class='fontColor_00FF00'>the color of this text is now green</div>
<div class='fontColor_0000FF'>the color of this text is now blue</div>
```

Comment: woah it's like magic!! thank you so much. it works just perfectly

Comment: could you please convert this js code into jq? im just not very familiar with js

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to do that:

```js
$('div[class^=fontColor').each(function(i,div){
  var c = $(this).attr("class");
  var color = '#' + c.split(/_/g)[1];
  $(this).css("color",color);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class='fontColor_0000ff'>the color of this text is now blue</div>

<div class='fontColor_bada55'>the color of this text is now green</div>
```

Comment: wow thank you this is really cool!:D but.. it somehow doesn't work for me.. does it for you.? could you maybe re-check the code?

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct version of `jQuery`. In my snippet I used jQuery 1.10.2 @valeria

Comment: nope.. still doesn't. error:{
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: works fine with me. Maybe the browser you are using is not up-to-date. Try from another device/browser. @valeria

Comment: @valeria do you mean it doesn't work in your app or doesn't work in this snippet?  Snippet works fine for me.

Comment: it doesn't work in this snippet. safari v12.0... oh well, maybe i just should update the browser or smth;0